# Distinguishing C++11 original type-name from typedef-name?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there anyway to distinguish the original name of a type from a typedef-name for that type?

For example:

```
class C1 {};

typedef C1 C2;
```

C1 and C2 both now name the same type.  In code after the above, is there ever a case where an occurence of the name C1 refering to the type in question cannot be replaced with C2 (or visa versa)?

Answer (score 5):

A typedef creates an alias, and they are indistinguishable as a type. There are on the other hand some specific syntax constructs that require the real type and not the typedef-ed (declaration/definition of constructor/destructors...), but that is a different question. As a type they are indistinguishable.

Comment: Are you aware if that is the only case (constructors/destructors)?  ie What are the other syntax constucts apart from constructors/destructors?

Comment: @user1131467 See $7.1.3 for more information on `typedef`. In regards to your comment $7.1.3/8 and $7.1.6.3 may give further clarification.

Comment: You might want to read up on the _injected class name_. Inside `C1` there are special ruls for looking up the name `C1`. But since `C2` names the same class, looking up `C1` in `C2` is also special. OTOH, `C2` is not injected in `C1`.

Comment: Also you can't forward declare a typedeffed class name.

Answer (score 3):

They are *completely* indistinguishable following the `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

from the [Complete Reference](http://www.mhprofessional.com/product.php?cat=39&isbn=0072121246) :

> "C allows you to explicitly define new data type names by using the keyword typedef. You are not actually creating a new data type, but rather defining a new name for an existing type."

What's interesting is (maybe) C++1Y will implement a strong-typed typededef (called *opaque typedef* ) which is not interchangeable will the base name : [PDF Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3515.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For reasons of C compatibility, you´re allowed to explicitly add `class` to C1: `class C1 foo;`, but `class C2 foo;` is illegal.

The reason for this is that C had separate namespaces for structs and functions, so you could ALSO have a function `void C1(int)`. This caused no ambiguities since each struct name had to be prefixed with `struct`. But if you typedef'ed `struct C1`, then the typedef name was not allowed to alias an existing function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one such case. You can't forward declare the type using the typedef. For example `class C2;` wouldn't be valid.

Other than that, a typedef creates an identity type alias and should be completely equivalent.